# Padding lists inside nested list to make all of uniform length

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to solve a problem that given a nested list containing lists of variable size, create a nested list that contains lists of uniform length equal to the maximum length among the lists inside the given nested list. Append empty strings as padding.

Input list:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David','Katherine'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

This is the list i made where width is the max value out of all sub-lists:

```
    mytable = []
    mytable2 = []
    mytable3 = []
    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        for j in range(width):
            if len(mytable) < width:
                mytable.append("")
            else:
                break
        mytable2.append(mytable)
```

I am trying to replace the values:(I can't think of conditions to stop the loop from overwriting the values.)

```
    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        for j in range(len(tableData[i])):
            if mytable[j] == "":
                mytable[j] = tableData[i][j]
            else:
                break
        mytable3.append(mytable)
```

The output I am getting:(all three sub-lists are getting overwritten simultaneously)

```
[['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', ''],
 ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', ''], 
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', '']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the maximum length of a sub-list. Iterate over the sub-lists and extend them accordingly:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David','Katherine'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

_max = max(map(len, tableData))

for e in tableData:
    e.extend([''] * (_max - len(e)))

print(tableData)
```

**Output:**

```
[['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', ''], ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David', 'Katherine'], ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you the better way to do it. Read through the whole answer to understand the code and procedure. I will not be using any more functions than those being used in the code snippets you have provided.
Assuming the Input nested list is

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David','Katherine'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

Now, let's iterate over this nested list to find the maximum length of lists inside this nested list.

```
max_length = 0
for inside_list in tableData:
    if len(inside_list) > max_length:
        max_length = len(inside_list)
```

Outputs `5`

Now, just iterate over the lists inside tableData and find how shorter are they than the maximum. Then append the empty string that many times to pad them to a uniform length.

```
for inside_list in tableData:
    shorter = max_length - len(inside_list)
    for i in range(shorter)
        inside_list.append("")
```

Running this will create your final list as

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana', ''],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David', 'Katherine'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose', '']]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the original problem was to add padding to the input list but while trying to solve that i found that i could not copy values from list to list. Is there a way to do that too ? I tried the nested for loop but it gave me the output as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Why wouldn't you can copy values from list to list? There are several methods like slicing, and also a deep copy/shallow copy concept in python to work upon copying the lists. Can you please be more specific what are u not able to do?

Comment: I should have said overwrite instead of copy. I want to take the values from a nested list and insert them into a nested list i have already created in the same indices.

Comment: @SuryaKannan, I would need the code which you are using to do that. For me it is a very simple process to be done, and I couldn't figure out what are you doing wrong.

Comment: I can't post the code here but the last code snippet before output in the post is what i am trying to do. and the output in the post is what i am getting. I tried to take the values from input list and insert into same indices in the created list but all sublists get overwritten at the sametime as shown in the ouput in the post and not one by one.